# Spring web returns invalid response

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-web

I am using `spring-web-4.3.10.RELEASE` library.

I call `postForEntity()` method of RestTemplate (entity returns by `getRestOperations()`) from this library like this:

```
getRestOperations().postForEntity(getEndpoint(), new HttpEntity<String>(requestStr, headers), String.class);
```

But the response is returned incorrect (tested by some tools like SOAP UI)

Json with an array [] that **is expected**:

```
{
  "Header": {
    "Security": {
      "Timestamp": {
        "Created": "2019-05-27T13:16:57Z",
        "Expires": "2019-05-27T13:18:27Z"
      }
    }
  },
  "Body": {
    "NResponse": {
      "NoteInqRec": [
        {
          "NoteInfo": {
            "BranchDetails": ""
          }
        },
        {
          "NoteInfo": {
            "BranchDetails": ""
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

And the response from code using spring-web lib **I got** (the json returned is not even valid):

```
{
  "Header": {
    "Security": {
      "Timestamp": {
        "Created": "2019-05-27T13:16:57Z",
        "Expires": "2019-05-27T13:18:27Z"
      }
    }
  },
  "Body": {
    "NResponse": {
      "NoteInqRec": 
        {
          "NoteInfo": {
            "BranchDetails": ""
          }
        },
        "NoteInqRec":
        {
          "NoteInfo": {
            "BranchDetails": ""
          }
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Please, assist

Comment: Why are you expecting a String as returned object and not some kind of DTO?

Comment: You should make use of POJO matching to the JSON structure and pass that instead of String.